# How do I integrate oscar's product render template tags with my own template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-oscar

I am developing an ecommerce website with the help of django-oscar. I decided to use the template tags and dashboard of oscar while trying to only change the templates with my own.

*I am sorry that the description of the question is so long but I assume you would need to understand my work process to understand the problem. In the description below, I start with my basic settings and template integration and work my way to the catalogue.html which is where I am facing the problem. My main problem statement is in bold*

I have forked the oscar's catalogue app with my own. Right now my `settings.py` looks like this:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/local')
OSCAR_TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/oscar')
TEMP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'allstatic')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_in_env'),]


# Application definition


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',

    #Custom Made Apps
    'appdir.catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig',

    #Oscar Apps
    'oscar',
    'oscar.apps.analytics',
    'oscar.apps.checkout',
    'oscar.apps.address',
    'oscar.apps.shipping',
    # 'oscar.apps.catalogue',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews',
    'oscar.apps.partner',
    'oscar.apps.basket',
    'oscar.apps.payment',
     ...
]

SITE_ID = 1


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR, OSCAR_TEMP_DIR, TEMP_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'oscar.apps.search.context_processors.search_form',
                'oscar.apps.checkout.context_processors.checkout',
                'oscar.apps.customer.notifications.context_processors.notifications',
                'oscar.core.context_processors.metadata',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have my own templates that I have integrated into the app by subclassing the parent base.html i.e oscar's base.html:

My base.html lives inside the `project_dir/templates/local`

```
# base.html
{% extends 'oscar/base.html' %}

...
```

**I am trying to create a product catalogue page that showcases all the products. I can view the products in the database from the oscar's dashboard and even the admin page. However, it fails to render the `product.htm`l page that I am trying to use of sandbox site.**

Here is how my catalogue.html looks like.

```
{% extends "category-base.html" %}

{% load basket_tags %}
{% load category_tags %}
{% load product_tags %}
{% load i18n %}

    {% block header %} 
     ...
    {% endblock header %}

    <main>

    {% block column_left %}
        <div class="block">

            {% category_tree as tree_categories %}
            {% if tree_categories %}
                <h6 class="text-uppercase">Product Categories</h6>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    {% for tree_category in tree_categories %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ tree_category.url }}" class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                {% if tree_category.pk == category.pk %}
                                    <span>{{ tree_category.name }}</span>
                                {% else %}
                                    <span>{{ tree_category.name }}</span>
                                {% endif %}
                            </a>

                            {% if tree_category.has_children %}
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            {% else %}
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% comment %} #num_to_close A list indicating the number of leaf branches that
                        this category terminates. 
                        {% endcomment %}
                        {% for n in tree_category.num_to_close %}
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <!--/Left Column Ends-->
    {% endblock column_left %}

<!-- Main Content Panel -->

    {% block column_right %}

        <form method="get" class="form-horizontal">
           ...

        </form>

        <!--Main Content-->

        {% if products %}
            <section>
                <div>
                    <ol class="row">
                        {% for product in products %}
                            <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{% render_product product %}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ol>
                    {% include "oscar/partials/pagination.html" %}
                </div>
            </section>
        {% else %}
            <p class="nonefound">{% trans "No products found." %}</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!--/Main Content-->


    {% endblock column_right %}
```

**Here the category tree in the block 'column_left' is rendered perfectly according to the catalog hierarchy. However, the product template tags inside the block 'column_right' do not yield anything. I checked the sandbox site, and all the uploaded products are rendered there.**

**However,`{% if products %}` tag yields passes the control to else and `<p class="nonefound">{% trans "No products found." %}</p>` is rendered.**

Oscar's product_tags.py inside the `projectenv/lib/site-packages/oscar/templatetags/` looks like this:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_product(context, product):
    """
    Render a product snippet as you would see in a browsing display.

    This templatetag looks for different templates depending on the UPC and
    product class of the passed product.  This allows alternative templates to
    be used for different product classes.
    """
    if not product:
        # Search index is returning products that don't exist in the
        # database...
        return ''

    names = ['oscar/catalogue/partials/product/upc-%s.html' % product.upc,
             'oscar/catalogue/partials/product/class-%s.html'
             % product.get_product_class().slug,
             'oscar/catalogue/partials/product.html']
    template_ = select_template(names)
    context = context.flatten()

    # Ensure the passed product is in the context as 'product'
    context['product'] = product
    return template_.render(context)
```

I checked the oscar/catalogue/partials/products.html and I couldn't find anything wrong there:

```
{% load display_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load image_tags %}
{% load reviews_tags %}

{% block product %}
    <article class="product_pod">
        {% block product_image %}
            <div class="image_container">
                {% with image=product.primary_image %}
                    {% oscar_thumbnail image.original "x155" upscale=False as thumb %}
                    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <img src="{{ thumb.url }}" alt="{{ product.get_title }}" class="thumbnail">
                    </a>
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block product_review %}
            {% iffeature "reviews" %}
                <p class="star-rating {{ product.rating|as_stars }}">
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                    <i class="icon-star"></i>
                </p>
            {% endiffeature %}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block product_title %}
            <h3><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}" title="{{ product.get_title }}">{{ product.get_title|truncatewords:4 }}</a></h3>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block product_price %}
            <div class="product_price">
                {% include "oscar/catalogue/partials/stock_record.html" %}
                {% if not product.is_parent and not product.has_options %}
                    {% include "oscar/catalogue/partials/add_to_basket_form_compact.html" %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
    </article>
{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand why the products are not being rendered or where the problem lies. If there was an error in template tags I would have received some warning in debug. I think the problem lies with `product.html` page or the `{% if products%}` statement but I cannot figure out exactly.

Also, any critical feedbacks and advice on good practices will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the template tag. It's simply that your view is returning no results. Hard to say why that is from what you have shared - the obvious things to check would be that (a) you actually have products in the database and (b) you've updated the search index.

Comment: Yes I have products in my database, which is displayed when I try to show it through sandbox template(default oscar template). I dont understand why it is not rendered through my template.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do the same thing as you, but it doesn't work this way. Instead of creating a shop page of your own, just try to modify the shop page that already is there by default (from oscar) I think it's called browse.html (templates/oscar/catalogue/browse.html). This page (as well as the rest of the pages from the folder templates) contains multiple partials, you need to go in each and one of them and just change the css to make it look like you want. In partials/product.html is just the product card not the entire shop page, that is browse.html. Oscar pages inherits partials. It's just how it's built.